# MeshFunctions in ParametricPlot with BSplineFunction for parameter extraction

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics, parametric-functions

I would like to use `MeshFunctions` in `ParametricPlot` in combination with `BSplineFunction` to extract parameters for points on the curve.

I have a set of points:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {3, 4}, {-1, 4}, {-4, 0}, {-4, -3}};
```

Then I use `BSplineFunction` to create a BSpline curve. `BSplineFunction[...]][u]` gives the point on a B-spline curve corresponding to parameter `u`.

I want to find the parameter `u` corresponding to a point on the curve. For that I can use `FindRoot`:

```
u = 
  Table[
    u /. FindRoot[function[u][[1]] == pts[[i, 1]], {u, 0.0, 1.0}], 
    {i, Length[pts - 1]}
  ]
```

I would like to use `MeshFunctions` for this. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the definition of `function` in your code? What advantage do you seek from `MeshFunctions` that is not achievable with the solution you have now?

Comment: The `pts` is control points, does not on the curve. BTW, `function[u][[1]]` is  `{0., 3., -1., -4., -4.}`, so the `FindRoot`  does not take effect.

Comment: Hi MarcoB, FindRoot doesn't find all solutions, especially if for one parameter u two points exist on the y-axis. Using MeshFunctions give me the points. How to obtain from these points the parameter u. I would really appreciate this.

Comment: Hi cvgmt, 

There is a misunderstanding, sorry. I don't need the control points. I would like to get from a arbitrary point {x[u], y[u]} on the curve the corresponding parameter u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect maybe like this.

```
Clear[pts, f, reg];
pts = {{0, 0}, {3, 4}, {-1, 4}, {-4, 0}, {-4, -3}};
f = BSplineFunction[pts];
reg = ParametricRegion[{Indexed[f@u, 1], 
     Indexed[f@u, 2]}, {{u, 0, 1}}] // DiscretizeRegion;
Manipulate[Module[{sol, u, q},
  sol = NMinimize[{EuclideanDistance[{Indexed[f@u, 1], 
        Indexed[f@u, 2]}, pt], 0 <= u <= 1}, u][[2]];
  q = f@u /. sol;
  ParametricPlot[f@u, {u, 0, 1}, 
   Epilog -> {Text[Style["u=" <> ToString[u /. sol], Red, 14], 
      q, {0, -2}]}, PlotRange -> 5]], {{pt, f@.5}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> (pt = RegionNearest[reg]@#; &)}]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear cvgmt. This is great. Thank you very very much. I'm really grateful.

Answer (score 2):

We may create a table of {BSpline,u} and then fit a function to it. This function will then return "u" from a data pair {x,y}:

With the BSpline:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {3, 4}, {-1, 4}, {-4, 0}, {-4, -3}};
crv[u_] = BSplineFunction[pts][u]
```

we create the table:

```
dat = Table[{crv[u], u}, {u, 0, 1, 0.01}];
```

then we define our function:

```
fun[{x_, y_}] = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x, y]
```

To test, we may write:

```
fun[crv[0.4]] == 0.4

(* True *)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you very much. This is also a nice solution. Thanks.